# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function plugin_dir_path(), 0 passed in https://FILE DIR

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i need to include a - plugin functions and classes so i can work on it outside the plugin area
for example
i have a plugin called pluginA

pluginA DIR ==

```
    pluginA [ all inside **/plugins/pluginA ]

                      |
                      |
                      |___ class-pluginA.php
pluginA-loader.php____|
                      |____ includes ____ assets ___ images
```

---

i need to includes some function from plugin a to plugin b

pluginB DIR ==

```
    pluginB [ all inside **/plugins/pluginB ]

                      |
                      |___[SUB-FOLDER] * functions.php
                      |___ class-pluginB.php
pluginB-loader.php____|
                      |____ includes ____ assets ___ images
```

how's im trying to do it in PluginB [Functions.php] :: ==
i want to include a function/class from plugin a to plugin b

**input**

```
include_once (WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/pluginA/pluginA-loader.php');
```

**output**

```
Warning: include_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

When I Include a plugin bbp-loader.php

also i did ::

**input**

```
 echo plugin_dir_path() . '/plugina/functions.php';
```

**output**

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function plugin_dir_path(), 0 passed
```

if you have a fix please let me know (:

thanks

Comment: First: you want to use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` instead of `WP_PLUGIN_URL` (see [WordPress Constants](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants).) Second: read the documentation of the [plugin_dir_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) function and you'll see why you're getting that error message.

Comment: im using WP_PLUGIN_URL not WP_PLUGIN_DIR

Comment: That's the point of my previous comment: you should be using `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, not `WP_PLUGIN_URL`.

Comment: okay thanks , got it